# How do I queue a build and only run specific stages with the azure devops nuget?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm currently using the "azure devops nuget" (Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client) to interact with our azure devops build and pipelines.

But I don't really understand how I queue a new build and only run specific stages. So this is how my current code look:

```
var buildHttpClient = _vssConnection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var buildDefinition = await buildHttpClient.GetDefinitionAsync(projectId, buildDefinitionId);

await buildHttpClient.QueueBuildAsync(new Build 
{
   Definition = buildDefinition 
},
projectId);
```

I read somewhere that I instead could use `PipelinesHttpClient` but somehow I can't even create that one without getting an exception that says `Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)`. It also only contains a "StagesToSkip" which means that I need to find out all the stages name (but I maybe can access that somewhere?).

So is it possible to queue a specific stage with the `BuildHttpClient` or do I need to use `PipelinesHttpClient` and find all the stages names somehow?

Comment: Could you find a solution? I'm trying to manage access permissions for a service connection but getting 32 digit error too while using PipelinesHttpClient.

Comment: @EfeErdoğru maybe you already found a solution but I added part of the one that we're using.

Comment: Thanks @milleb for this specific task I used Rest API directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
var vssConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri("yourAzureDevopsUri"), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "yourPasswordOrPAT"));

var pipelineClient = new PipelinesHttpClient(vssConnection .Uri, vssConnection .Credentials);

var parameters = new RunPipelineParameters();
parameters.StagesToSkip.Add("WhatverStageYouWantToSkip");

var run = await pipelineClient.RunPipelineAsync(parameters, "YourProjectGUID", YourBuildDefinitionId);
```

The problem with this solution is that it is `StagesToSkip` and not `StagesToRun` so it's a bit backward. But we just keep a configuration with all possible stages and then we remove stages from that list when we only want to run that stage.