# How do I re-run an existing Azure DevOps pipeline using the Azure DevOps NuGet, for other stages?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This is a kind of follow-up to the [How do I queue a build and only run specific stages with the azure devops nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74044109/how-do-i-queue-a-build-and-only-run-specific-stages-with-the-azure-devops-nuget) question, which I was able to build upon in my previous [How do I run an Azure DevOps pipeline using the Azure DevOps NuGet and at the same time specify resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608105/how-do-i-run-an-azure-devops-pipeline-using-the-azure-devops-nuget-and-at-the-sa) question.

The original premise was to run a pipeline for only a sub-set of its available stages.
Now that this has been achieved, I would like to "append" to an existing run, by running it for other stages that were not included in the original run.

I can't find a suitable method for this, on the `Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelinesHttpClient` type.

Back when I was using a "classic" release pipeline, this was easily achieved, like this:

1. Create a release using the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Clients.ReleaseHttpClient`'s `CreateReleaseAsync` method
2. Deploy to a stage using the above mentioned client's `UpdateReleaseEnvironmentAsync` method per stage, as this method takes a release ID as input

The (obvious?) point of doing it like this is to perform a phased deployment over time, and being able to have a nice deployment status on a dashboard for a given release version.

Still wanting to reuse the existing pipeline "run", I've looked at the `PipelinesHttpClient` type for methods that would allow me to start a new run, but based on the existing run I have, with a modified set of stages.

It looks like I can only start brand new pipeline runs, though, as it only takes the pipeline identifier as input (in addition to the version and any resources, obviously).
Though this works, it makes for a somewhat cluttered status dashboard, as each run will only contain its specific set of stages, like this:

[image: Stage status for the same build version across different pipeline runs]

I would like all of these to appear on the same line, appended over time, just like when running the classic release pipeline.

The `Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.Run` instance I get when calling `pipelinesClient.GetRunAsync` is of no use either, as it contains only properties, and not any methods.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want the YAML pipeline to achieve the same function as the classic release pipeline, redeploying specific stages in a release without creating a new release. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

If I understand correctly, I'm afraid the YAML pipeline currently does not have such a feature. You can check directly on the UI, currently only "Rerun failed jobs" are supported. We know that YAML is the future. But so far, the YAML pipeline hasn't supported all features of the classic release pipeline.

As a workaround, it's suggested that you could use the classic release pipeline. Besides, I notice that there is already [a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Rerun-successful-stages-in-YAML-pipeline/884036?ftype=idea&q=redeploy+in+yaml+pipeline). You can submit a vote and follow it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your understanding is correct. I've now voted for the referenced feature request, although I see it has received little attention.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to "append" to an existing run, by running it for other stages that were not included in the original run.

Based on your requirement, you need to run the skipped stages in the existing YAML Pipeline Run.

There is no such method can achieve this feature(e.g. API, Pipeline UI, Azure DevOps Nuget Package) in Azure DevOps for the time being.

To run the skipped stages, you need to create a new pipeline run and include the related stages.

You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

Currently, Azure DevOps Yaml Pipeline only supports re-running **completed** Pipeline stages(fail or success).

For example:

Success:

[image]

Fail:

[image]

We can also using Rest API to re-run **completed** Pipeline stages.

```
PATCH: https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildid}/stages/{stagename}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Request body: `{"state":1,"forceRetryAllJobs":false}`

This API is also in the preview stage, so there is no corresponding azure devops nuget method to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your understanding is correct. I will have to make do with multiple runs for now then.

Comment: @MortenGrøtan Yes. This is the  the only way right now. hope the function will be added to azure devops in the future.